# Youtube Data Api multiplies by 2 your queries

Tags: json, api, youtube, youtube-api, cloud

This is a question most suitable for Youtube API developers. 
Having 2 queries performed to get the videoid and the title (first query)

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?safeSearch=moderate&order=relevance&part=snippet&q=".urlencode($q). "&maxResults=10&key=". $api;
```

and a second query to get the contentDetails to see if the video is licensed or not

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails&maxResults=10&id=".$vid."&key=". $api;
```

I was expecting the Google dashboard to show 2 queries, instead it shows a  4 queries.

I'd like a clue as to how google counts this searches. Anybody has checked this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to clear something regarding your issue. If your API requests returns multiple pages of results, this will add to the query as stated from [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost).

> **Note:** If your application calls a method, such as `search.list`, that
>   returns multiple pages of results, each request to retrieve an
>   additional page of results will incur the estimated quota cost.

It is due to requesting again a token for another result per page. You can also check the [Youtube Quota Calculator](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/determine_quota_cost) documentation for more details.

If this is not the case, this can be a bug. You can try to log the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com).

Comment: To get the ID of a video with licensedContent information you need to perform 2 queries. The Quota Calculator, gives a "price" of 5 given the search is for a video - snippet - contentDetails.  This is not what i'm asking. What I'm saying is that the dashboard registers 4 queries instead of the 2 calls, and the calls clearly specify 10 items each, no additional information. It looks very clear to me.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is **IF** the result of your query returns two pages, this will multiply into 2. I've just showed how the quota per each query costs. If this is not the case, you can log a bug issue for this.

Comment: Sorry but the result of 1 query returns 1 page of ten results, as specified on the query line you see above and checked looking at it. The result of the 2 queries returns 2 pages, the first one of ten, and second one of ten, also. Still, this is counted as 4 queries by google apis. A bug has filed but no response yet. Thanks